# Why can't download flash plugin for Debian?

Tags: debian, firefox, adobe-flash

Environment:debian8+firefox esr 45.8
I want to install flash plugin for my firefox.

[image]

Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because one of the following protocols (apt) isn't associated with any program or is not allowed in this context.

There is a material about apturl problem
[apturl for firefox](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/10/fixing-apturl-for-firefox-35-and-later.html)
Do as the webpage say.

```
sudo apt-get install apturl 
E: Package 'apturl' has no installation candidate
sudo aptitude search  apturl
get nothing
```

And it is no use to set  network.protocol-handler.app.apt in character chain with /usr/bin/apturl as value.

How to install flash plugin is another problem which can be solved this way.

```
1.add proper source into sources.list         
echo "deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list                 
2.sudo aptitude search flash                 

    p   browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash                                                 - PPAPI-host NPAPI-plugin adapter for pepperflash                                                  
    p   flashbake                                                                              - automated snapshots with git                                                                     
    p   flashbench                                                                             - identify flash storage properties                                                                
    v   flashblock                                                                             -                                                                                                  
    p   flashcache-dkms                                                                        - write-back block device cache for Linux (DKMS version)                                           
    p   flashcache-utils                                                                       - write-back block device cache for Linux (user space utilities)                                   
    v   flashgot                                                                               -                                                                                                  
    p   flashplayer-chromium                                                                   - Flash Player for Chromium (Pepper)                                                               
    p   flashplayer-mozilla                                                                    - Adobe Flash Player                                                                               
    i   flashplugin-nonfree                                                                    - Adobe Flash Player - browser plugin                                                              
    p   flashplugin-nonfree-extrasound                                                         - Adobe Flash Player platform support library for Esound and OSS           

3. apt-get update    
4. apt-get install  flashplayer-mozilla
```

The problem why **apt:adobe-flashplugin?channel=$distro-partner** can't be opened by firefox still remain.

Comment: is there any specific reason you don't just run `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree`?

Comment: Silly comment, agreed, but you should avoid flash plugins ... just saying, I am off back into my cave.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to follow instructions for Ubuntu, not Debian. While Ubuntu [does have](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) a package called `apturl`, the Debian [equivalent package](https://wiki.debian.org/AptProtocol) was apparently called `aptlinex` but since none of the links on that page work, it looks like it's no longer packaged in Debian.

So, just install it normally and forget about the fancy `apt://` links:

```
sudo apt-get install flash-plugin-nonfree
```

You might need to add the contrib repositories for this to work; check your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, look for lines of the form

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

(the URL might be different on your system) and add `contrib` to the end:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib
```

Comment: Unable to locate package flash-plugin-nonfree

Comment: How to install flash for my debian and why the url  `apt:adobe-flashplugin?channel=$distro-partner ` can't be opened are two problems.I have solved the first problem ,the second remains.

Comment: Like the answer says, `apt:` urls are a Ubuntu thing, and they don't work on Debian. You could try to compile the Ubuntu `apturl` package from source, but that probably won't work either, since it might try to activate repositories that won't work for Debian...

Comment: Looks like it's actually "flashplugin-nonfree" (without the first hyphen)

Answer (score 5):

flashplugin-nonfree is currently not available in debian 9 stable stretch. You can find it in the unstable repository but the package is still(!) having the following bug (I think the bartm dude died or something):

```
Setting up flashplugin-nonfree (1:3.7) ...
ERROR: wget failed to download http_://people.debian.org/~bartm/flashplugin-nonfree/D5C0FC14/fp.26.0.0.151.sha512.amd64.pgp.asc
```

You need to do it manually for firefox, maybe pepper works for chrome users.
Download the latest release of the plugin in tar.gz format from [Adobe](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/).

Note: if you need it for firefox be sure to click on 'need it for another computer' and select the npapi version.

As root, extract the tar.gz package and copy `libflashplayer.so` to `/usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree`
Give the file the following permission/ownership values:

```
chmod 644 /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
chown root:root /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so
```

Check that the relevant `/etc/alternatives` entry is correct (this shouldn't be required if the plugin was working properly before the upgrade)

```
update-alternatives --list flash-mozilla.so
```

should return `/usr/lib flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so`
If that's not the case, you can fix it with:

```
update-alternatives --quiet --install /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/flash-mozilla.so flash-mozilla.so /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree/libflashplayer.so 50
```

See the [Debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/FlashPlayer) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

For Debian you need to download the ".tar.gz for Linux" from Adobe, then copy it to /usr/lib/flashplugin-nonfree (because the flash-plugin-nonfree doesn't get updated as Adobe changes the link).